# Divine Spellcasting as an Arcane Spellcaster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3e, prestige-class, class

Is there a class that allows one to learn and cast Divine spells the way they can learn and cast Arcane spells? Without multiclassing specifically as a Divine spellcaster such as Cleric or Druid, but may include Prestige classes if any.

For example a Wizard, or Arcanist, that can also learn to cast Divine spells without having to take Cleric or other main divine spellcasting classes.

Comment: How essential is it that you're not a divine caster? There's [a class](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cwc/20061212) that pretty much plays as a wizard: int-based spells, memorized daily from a spellbook and learned from scrolls. It's a divine spellcaster, but it's not as tied to religion or devotion as a Cleric/Druid could be, and I could write an answer on it if it's ok for your prereqs.

Comment: How hard do you want it lawyered? Is the DM open to difficult, nonstandard readings that certainly violate intent but adhere strictly to letter?

Comment: My DM is pretty open minded, so long as things dont go TOO far...

I'm also open to listening to other classes, but mainly wish to focus on caster level and spell availability, hence making Rainbow Servant seem like an optimal choice at the moment. Savant, from Dragon Compendium can also cast Arcane and Divine spells, but the limitations of that class are too drastic for any real playability in my group... I was thinking more along the lines of Arcanist/Rainbow Servant...

Answer (score 8):

10 levels of the *Rainbow Servant* prestige class from page 54 of *Complete Divine* allows an arcane spellcaster full access to the Cleric spell list. They can learn and cast any spell from the Cleric spell list as if it was from the Arcane spellcasting class that allowed them entry into Rainbow Servant. Note that these spells still count as Divine spells for all purposes (most particularly Arcane Spell Failure.)

An important detail of the Rainbow Servant is that it gives full spellcasting progression. At first glance, it loses 4 spellcasting levels (from the table), but the text of the class doesn't mention this. Despite this almost certainly being an oversight, there is a rule that 'text trumps table', so the text overrides the table and you don't lose any spellcasting. *Complete Divine* has received both errata and reprints, and neither has changed the text or the table in question.